# I want to have two products on a mobile view woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My website is: https://zaariya.com/

I want two products in a mobile view and I've tried each and every thing to show two products only in `media@(max-width:481)`.

When I turn it into `481` it shows a single one.

I want to show two products on mobile, please help me.

I have tried changing the css of `g product-inner` but nothing happens.

I have searched the internet and placed additional css also, but that does not work for me.

This theme I purchased from theme forest.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .columns-4 .card-item {
      width: 50% !important;
    }
}
```

I will get something like this:

[image: your products view on mobile[1]]

Comment: I have paste into additional css and nothing happen did it work for you?

Comment: I think you should add `!important` so it will be `width: 50% !important;`

Comment: It worked thanks i did the same for this 
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .columns-4 .card-item {
      width: 50% !important;
    }
}